# Can't install PyOpenCL

Tags: python, build-tools, pyopencl, visual-c++

I'm trying to install PyOpenCl on my Windows 10 device. I'm using the command:

```
pip install pyopencl
```

I get the error

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools"

This link doesn't exist anymore, all solutions I find link to this. I installed a new Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools version, doesn't work. I downloaded Microsoft Visual Build Tools 2015, which is supposed to be the 14.0 version but it sill gives me the same error.

Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried installing from `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2015`? In windows `Command Prompt` there may not be all required paths setup in order to install `pyopencl`. OpenCL SDK may be required too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.  I ended up trying a few things and getting it to work.

1) Updated pip

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

2) Update setuptools

```
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

3) Install Microsoft 2017 build tools (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), select "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017." Download install, etc